# Under any circumstances is it possible for `foo == null` to be false, when `foo` is indeed null?

Tags: java, null

I am debugging an application that is designed to gracefully handle a case of `foo` being `null`. When checking a log from production however, a `NullPointerException` was thrown trying to access a method of `foo` after it should have gracefully been handled.

it looks like this

```
if (foo == null) {
    throw new GracefulException();
}

Bar bar = foo.getBar();
```

So with that code in place, a `NullPointerException`occurred in production when calling `foo.getBar()`.

My question is simply this: Has anyone ever heard of funky behavior like this happening or even being possible? And if so, what could be causing it?

Comment: No. This is not possible. My money is on a badly written `try ... catch`.

Comment: Can you add a full stack trace?

Comment: @NilsH The code I posted in my question is a highly abstracted example of the actual production code. A stacktrace would be useless unless I greatly enhanced the example code to reflect the actual code, and did the work of modifying line numbers and removing sensitive information from the stacktrace.

Comment: @NilsH However, I will consider doing this if I cannot figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: is there parallel execution involved somehow?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle It is a web application running on Tomcat. `foo` gets its value from a static helper class that retrieves session data.

Comment: @zero01alpha: then SLaks's answer applies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the call stack; that might be coming from inside `getBar()`.

Also, if `foo` isn't a local variable, some other thread might set it to null after the `if`.

Comment: `foo` is a local variable, but it gets its value from a static helper class that retrieves session data. This is a web application running on a Tomcat server. I'm not sure if I can check the call stack from `getBar()` because the only evidence I have of this even happening is a log file that only dumps the stack trace of an unhandled exception. The only reason I even know it is coming from `foo.getBar()` is because that is the only thing happening in the line number specified in the stack trace.

Comment: @zero01alpha If `foo` is a local variable, it cannot be updated between these lines of code.

Comment: How could something be coming from `getBar()`, when the attempt to call `getBar()` is what results in the `NullPointerException`? Forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @zero01alpha: Is `getBar()` at the _top_ of the stack trace? Also, is it possible the `getBar()` was inlined?

Comment: The method that *calls* `foo.getBar()` is at the top of my stack trace, and the only reason I know `foo.getBar()` is causing the null pointer is because of the line number included in the stack trace.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by the method being inlined, I am not familiar with that term.

Answer (score 1):

> No. `foo == null` can never be `false`, if `foo` is `null`.

There could be these possible cases:

1. Your application is multi-threaded and foo is a shared field that is not synchronized properly. If this is the case, then synchronization is required. As `foo` is a local variable, this case is not applicable here.
2. Exception is coming from inside `foo.getBar()`. This case can be easily identified by the stack trace getting generated. Check if the method name is present in the stack trace.

**For example,** consider below code:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Temp().functionA();
    }

    void functionA() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        //foo = null; //Line 1
        String str = foo.getBar();
    }
}

class Foo {
    Object x = new Object();

    public String getBar() {
        //x = null; //Line 2
        return x.toString();
    }
}
```

If `foo` is `null` (Line 1 not commented), stack trace would be like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Temp.functionA(Temp.java:9)
at Temp.main(Temp.java:3)
```

If `x` is `null` (Line 2 not commented), stack trace would be like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Foo.getBar(Temp.java:16)
at Temp.functionA(Temp.java:8)
at Temp.main(Temp.java:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `foo.getBar()` is mentioned in the stack trace, the exception is thrown inside that method and you're looking in wrong place.

If the top of the stack trace is the method that contains this `foo.getBar()` call, it's `foo` being `null`.

Since you write that `foo` is a local variable, this is *not* due to some other thread interfering - another thread can never set the value of your local variable (most it can do is modify it's content).

- Check that there's no statement setting `foo` to `null` between the check and the method call.
- Check that there's no way to avoid the check (i.e. that the check is not in a conditional block)
- Check that there's no catch block catching `GracefulException` between the check and the method call.